# Bash - Rename files to base64 value of the filenames

Tags: bash, rename, filenames

I have some .mp4 files and want to rename their names to base64 values of the filenames but keep the extension out of base64 encoding. I need a bash script for this purpose.

```
e.g.: file is file-fly34567.mp4 (and others)
echo 'file-fly34567' | base64 --> ZmlsZS1mbHkzNDU2Nw==
then 'file-fly34567.mp4' -> 'ZmlsZS1mbHkzNDU2Nw==.mp4'
```

Comment: Beware of the '/' character that can appear in base64 encoding. In many filesystems this is not a valid filename character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it (assuming you're in the directory containing the .mp4 files):

```
for f in *.mp3
do
    new_name=$(echo -n "${f%.*}" | base64 -w0)
    cp "$f" "$new_name.${f##*.}"
    #mv "$f" "$new_name.${f##*.}"
done
```

Uncomment the `mv` line and remove the `cp` line to move rather than copy.

The `-w0` option to `base64` disables line wrapping. Without it, you'll get question marks in the resulting file names in case they're longer than the default length. From [man base64](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64):

```
-w, --wrap=COLS
      wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76).  Use 0 to disable line wrapping
```

You can pass in multiple file extensions by simply adding them at the top. E.g.

```
for f in *.mp4 *.mp3 *.flv
```

Comment: Thanks this works very well but there is a issue with long filenames. because in base64 it breaks the long encoded value to a new line. So if this script can trim that _CRLF_ then everything would be fine. @jDo

Comment: @ianmel99 Nice catch. It's a feature of the base64 program. I've disabled it in my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can rename (move) a with with `mv`. To get the base64 part you can use a command substitution:

```
mv -- "$file" "$(printf "%s" "${file%.mp4}" | base64).mp4"
```

If you want to change the file names for all mp4 files in a directory:

```
for file in *.mp4; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  mv -- "$file" "$(printf "%s" "${file%.mp4}" | base64).mp4"
done
```

Or rename all files in a directory:

```
for file in *; do
# for file in * .*; do # for hidden files
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  mv -- "$file" "$(printf "%s" "${file%.*}" | base64).${file##*.}"
done
```

And rename all files from a newline separated file:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  mv -- "$file" "$(printf "%s" "${file%.*}" | base64).${file##*.}"
done < file.txt
```

As you can see all the above commands uses the same core part `mv -- "$file" "..."` but with different loops. which can be changed to suit your needs.

Comment: `[ -e "$file" ]` <- nice touch, just in case. There's also the `-f` option for "FILE exists and is a regular file" which might be better since it'll exclude any directories ending in ".mp4"

Comment: It's a good trick but it will work only of files with the same (and know from the beginning) extension...

Comment: Oh I missed he wanted to change only one file type

Answer (score 1):

```
rename 'use MIME::Base64;
        s/\.mp4$//;
        $_ = encode_base64($_, "") . ".mp4"' *.mp4
```

Comment: Note on some systems this is called `perl-rename` While `rename` is comming from util-linux

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have more than 1 file, and they may have different extensions. Therefore I will give you an example of changing **only** the name of the file.

**change multiple files REGARDLESS their extensions**

```
fullfiles=(/home/user/.../myfile.mp4 /home/user2/.../myfile2.png ...)

for fullfile in "${fullfiles[@]}"; do
    dirname=$(dirname "$fullfile")
    filename=$(basename "$fullfile")
    extension=${filename##*.}
    filename=${filename%.*}
    base64name=$(echo -n "$filename" | base64)
    mv "$fullfile" "$dirname/$base64name.$extension"
done
```

This will change the names of each file in the list to its base64 without changing the extensions!